# Strange server host name in tomcat access logs

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7

Here is an exert from my `localhost_access_log.*.txt` for a client IP address (113.163.190.116) talking to my server (localhost).  However, there's no way the remote IP accessed this server through localhost.  So the question is how is localhost ending up in the server host name?

```
113.163.190.116 | localhost | "GET / HTTP/1.0" | - | [http-bio-8080-exec-7] | - | -
104.255.46.23 | 1.2.3.4 | "GET / HTTP/1.0" | - | [http-bio-8080-exec-4] | - | -
```

I see a similar issue with 1.2.3.4 showing up in my logs as well.  I suspect these are bad actors trying to do something nefarious, but I'm curious how they are connecting to my server.  The AccessLogValve for this is using %v.